# Exact Differential with $k$ variables

Tags: calculus

We know that if $f=f(x,y)$ then we can write
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$$
So if $df$ is an [Exact Differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
must hold.

But, what conditions over the derivatives of $f$ must hold when $f=f(x_1,...,x_k)$ with $k\geq3$, such that $df$ is still an Exact Differential?

Intuitively I'd say that it must hold:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$ $\forall$ $x_i \neq x_j$ $\in $ {$x_1,...,x_k$}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. To give a necessary condition for exactness of 1-form
$$df=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i$$
We need $df$ also to be closed. That is
$$d(df)=\sum_{i,j=1}^k\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}dx_j\right)\wedge dx_i=\sum_{i\neq j}^k\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}\right)dx_i\wedge dx_j=0$$
which requires
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}$$
Next by [Poincare lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_lemma#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma), if closed form $df$ is defined on a connected space $X$, then $df$ is also exact.

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest me a book where I can check this result, please?

Comment: @Anuar Geometry of Physics by Frankel